# How can I name each bar label in a stacked bar graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple DataFrame here. I am not able to understand or find easy way to label each bar.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

India = pd.DataFrame({'Year' : [1980 , 1984, 1988 , 1992, 1996 , 2000 , 2004, 2008 , 2012, 
                       2016 , 2020] , 
                 'Gold' : [1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
                 'Silver': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,2],
                 'Bronze' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,4,1,4] })
India = India.set_index('Year')

India.plot(kind='bar' , stacked = 'true' , figsize = (8,5))
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)
plt.legend(['Gold Medal','Silver Medal','Bronze Medal'] , title = "Medal Category" )
plt.title("Olympic Medal Trend - India (1980 - 2020)")
plt.xlabel("Summer Olympics held(years)")
plt.ylabel("Number of Medals won")

totals = India.sum(axis=1)
print(totals)
y_offset = 4
```

I am not getting how to proceed further . I want only the totals or height of "y" as the bar label.

I tried solutions present here but always got label for each single bar and not for the whole bar.

Comment: See this: [https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `plt.text`:

```
for x, y in enumerate(totals):
    if y != 0:
        plt.text(x, y, y, ha='center', va='bottom')
```

[image: Total over barplot]

Comment: Sorry was typing on my phone... Only saw your answer now

Comment: Thanks Corralien for your solution . Really helpful . Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to label the bars with the total. You were almost there, I see you pre-computed the totals and defined an offset. Now you need to catch the Axes object (`ax = India.plot(...)`), and loop over the totals to add the texts:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
India = pd.DataFrame({'Year' : [1980 , 1984, 1988 , 1992, 1996 , 2000 , 2004, 2008 , 2012, 
                       2016 , 2020] , 
                 'Gold' : [1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
                 'Silver': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,2],
                 'Bronze' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,4,1,4] })
India = India.set_index('Year')
ax = India.plot(kind='bar' , stacked = 'true' , figsize = (8,5))
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)
plt.legend(['Gold Medal','Silver Medal','Bronze Medal'] , title = "Medal Category" )
plt.title("Olympic Medal Trend - India (1980 - 2020)")
plt.xlabel("Summer Olympics held(years)")
plt.ylabel("Number of Medals won")

totals = India.sum(axis=1)
print(totals)
y_offset = .2

for x, t in enumerate(totals):
    ax.text(x, t+y_offset, t, ha='center')
```

Output:
[image: labeled barplot]

Comment: Thanks , explanation helped a lot. I didn't know about built-in "enumerate" function -- thanks for the solution

Comment: I hope to see you in top10 for this quarter :-)